# Series $\sum(-1)^{a(n)}\frac1{a(n)}$ converging to infinity with $a:\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$ a bijection

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I'd love to get a hint or direction on this and figure out a solution myself:

Construct a bijection: $$\: f:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N} $$
such that:
$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} -1^{f(n)}\frac{1}{f(n)} = \infty $$
I thought of something like below to eliminate all series elements that are negative:
$$
f(n):= 
\left \{
\begin{array}{ll}
n^{odd} \rightarrow n-1 \\
n^{even} \rightarrow n\\
\end{array}
\right.
$$
But then $f(n)$ cannot be a bijection. Another way would be to transform the fraction $\frac{1}{f(n)}$ into something that is divergent, but I don't see how that would be possible in an $\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ map.

---

**EDIT:** Deleted the suggestion that the resulting series would be a harmonic or geometric series.

---

Comment: You mean $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{f(n)}\frac{1}{f(n)} = \infty?$$

Comment: Yes, I did but I don't see what i did wrong.

Comment: The series you are interested in are neither alternating nor harmonic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The even positive integers can be partitioned into consecutive blocks $E_1 < E_2 < E_3 < \cdots $ such that

$$\sum_{n\in E_k} 1/n > 2\,\,\,\text{for each } k.$$

Now think of listing $\mathbb N$ as $E_1$ followed by $1,$ then $E_2$ followed by $3,$ then $E_3$ followed by $5,$ etc.  This defines a bijection $f$ of $\mathbb N$ onto $\mathbb N$ for which

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{f(n)}\frac{1}{f(n)} \ge 1+1+\cdots = \infty.$$

Comment: Yes, I see. It took me a while but I get it now. I would have never come up with that on my own. Can you give me a Theorem or something that made you think it through this way?

Comment: Are you familiar with the Riemann rearrangement theorem?

Comment: No I was not actually and It would have been helpful. For some reason our prof decided to teach us the opposite, namely that any permutations of absolutely convergent series converge to the original limit. I actually have no idea why, because Riemanns Theorem seems far more important.

Comment: Actually the result on absolutely convergent series is probably more important; that is used all the time. I didn't use the RRT above, but once you see its proof, you enter a new world where groupings such as the one I used seem natural.

Comment: It is mind bending, and I am still trying to wrap my head around it. One last question though, I think you made an error: shouldn’t you do E by summing 1/n > 2k instead of 1/n > 2 since you subtract the k-th uneven Element of N to get a net of +1 which for any uneven N >1 would result in a net negative?

Comment: I think we're fine. We have $$\sum_{n\in E_k} 1/n - \frac{1}{2k-1}> 2-1\,\,\,\text{for each } k.$$

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you mean a geometric series because that's not what you've written so my answer will be pointing you towards a rearrangement of the series $$\sum_{n\geq 1} \frac{(-1)^n}{n} $$ which will diverge. We can do this because that series above is *conditionally convergent.*

Let $a_i = \frac{1}{2i}$ and $b_j = -\frac{1}{2j-1}$ for $i,j\geq 1$, then we will arrange the $a_i$ and $b_j$ so that their sum converge. Let $n_1$ be minimal such that $$a_1 + a_2 + \cdots + a_{n_1} \geq -b_1 + 1$$ Now let $n_2$ be minimal such that $$a_{n_1+1} + \cdots + a_{n_2}\geq  -b_2 + 1$$

and continue in this way. Then $a_{n_{k-1}+1} + \cdots+ a_{n_k} + b_k \geq 1$ for all $k$  and so $$a_1 + a_2 + \cdots + a_{n_1} + b_1 + a_{n_1 + 1}  + \cdots + a_{n_2} + b_2 + \cdots $$ diverges. Hopefully this should be enough for you to construct your bijection.

Comment: "I don't think you mean a geometric series because that's not what you've written"  But OP has written the word "geometric series" *both* in the title *and* in the question body.  Your series is *not* something that OP asks for.

Comment: This series is $\sum (-1)^{f(n)} \frac{1}{f(n)}$ for a bijection $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ (which isn't a geometric series)

Comment: So you're admitting that you're not answering the question?

Comment: That series is in the question? I think OP is mistaken as characterising it as a geometric sequence

Comment: Yes, ODF is right, I was mistaken. Sorry for that.

Comment: I withdraw my previous comments to this answer due to OP's edit.

Answer (score 1):

My answer addresses to the *original* question.

It's *impossible* to find a bijection $f: \Bbb{N}\to\Bbb{N}$ such that the alternating sum of the reciprocals is an alternating divergent geometric series.

To make $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{f(n)}\frac{1}{f(n)} = \infty$$ an alternating divergent *geometric* series, you need $\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = -M < -1$ for some constant $M > 1$, where $a_n = (-1)^{f(n)}\dfrac{1}{f(n)}$.  (You need *constant* ratio $\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ for *geometric* series, and if $0 < M < 1$, the series is *absolutely convergent*.  If $M = 1$, $f$ is *not* a bijection.)  The common ratio becomes $$-M = \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = (-1)^{f(n+1) - f(n)}\frac{f(n)}{f(n+1)}.$$
Since the codomain of $f$ is $\Bbb{N}$, $\dfrac{f(n)}{f(n+1)} = M > 1$.  It's easy to see that $f(n) = \dfrac{1}{M^n} \in (0,1)$, contradicting the condition that the codomain of $f$ is $\Bbb{N}$.

Comment: Thanks for answering the original question, which was misleading. Sorry for that.

Comment: @lthz It's noted.  Please be aware that [invalidating an existing answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/26022/290189) through editing a question is *not* desirable.  Users with over 2k reputation can edit (i.e. rollback) *any* existing posts.  Therefore, such edit can be undone by any 2k user.  However, to respond to questions "[in the spirit in which they are asked](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26022/changing-the-question-and-invalidating-previous-answer#comment102675_26049)", I'll leave your questoin as-is.  However, please avoid that in the future.

Comment: okay noted, thanks!